# Google Map v3 - Cordova - map center is not changed on drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

I am trying to keep a marker in the center of the map during a drag. I've tried to use the drag event, But to no avail. 
I also started a setInterval routine to print the center and it did not change during the drag. Am I doing something wrong ? Is there another way to keep a marker in the center ?

Here is my event listener.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MapPage.map,'center_changed', function() {
    if (MapPage.el.find('.selectedMenu').hasClass("rdv")){

        var center = MapPage.map.getCenter();
        MapPage.rdvMarker.setPosition(center);

        //setInterval(function(){google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'dragend');console.log(MapPage.map.getCenter())},200);
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean the marker in the center will remain constant and not moving with drag?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the marker at the center of the map all the time! So whenever you will drag, it will give bring the marker at the center of the map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
    // 0.1 seconds after the center of the map has changed,
    // set back the marker position.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        marker.setPosition(center);
    }, 1);
});
```